# Angular ng-options values are not set using select as label syntax

Tags: angularjs

When I try the following code:

```
<select name="test" id="test" ng-model="test"
    ng-options="c.id as c.n for c in [{n:'t1',id:'123'}]">
</select>
```

I get

```
<select name="test" id="test" ng-model="test" > 
   <option value="0" selected="selected" label="t1">t1</option> 
</select>
```

Why the value is not '123' per angular's ng-options syntax.

Thanks,

Comment: It's not like a normal form field where the `value` is sent when the form is submitted. The `ng-model` binding will set the value appropriately. See http://plnkr.co/edit/sbGnniTffW9iXT251Gjd?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

That is because when the options are created by `ng-options` by iterating over the array, the value of each option element is the loop couter. However your `test` variable contains the value `item.age`. You can check it by printing it like `{{test}}`.

You can achieve what you want like this

```
<select name="test" id="test" ng-model="test" > 
 <option ng-repeat="c in [{n:'t1',id:'123'}]" value="{{c.id}}" >{{c.n}}</option> 
</select>
```